# How to show minute, second, hour in time progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a time progress bar. I use this code. In this time bar, I get the time in seconds, but I want to show minute, second, hour in the time progress bar.

```js
var timer = 0,
    timeTotal = 2500,
    timeCount = 20,
    timeStart = 0,
    cFlag;

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100,
        y = x.toFixed(3);
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').css("left", x + "%").text((percentage / 1000).toFixed(2) + "\00a0s");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    var perc = new Date().getTime() - timeStart;
    if(perc < timeTotal) {
        updateProgress(perc);
        timer = setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeCount);
    } else {
       updateProgress(timeTotal);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
        if (cFlag == undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cFlag = true;
            timeStart = new Date().getTime();
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else if (!cFlag) {
            cFlag = true;
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cFlag = false;
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/McNetic/hnfRe/397](http://%20jsfiddle.net/McNetic/hnfRe/397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. [DEMO LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfRe/401/)

```
<div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid grey; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
<div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: lightblue; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
<div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">0&nbsp;s</div>
</div>

<p>Click once to start!</p>
<p>Click again to toggle Start/Stop</p>
```

JS...

```
var timer = 0,
    timeTotal = 250000,
    timeCount = 20,
    timeStart = 0,
    cFlag;

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100,
        y = x.toFixed(3);
        var totalSec= (percentage / 1000);
         var min = parseInt(totalSec/60);
         var sec = parseInt(totalSec%60);
         var hr= parseInt(min/60);
          min = parseInt(min % 60);
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').css("left", x + "%").text(hr+":"+min+":"+sec + "");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    var perc = new Date().getTime() - timeStart;
    if(perc < timeTotal) {
        updateProgress(perc);
        timer = setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeCount);
    } else {
          updateProgress(timeTotal);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
        if (cFlag == undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cFlag = true;
            timeStart = new Date().getTime();
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else if (!cFlag) {
            cFlag = true;
            animateUpdate();
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cFlag = false;
        }
    });
});
```

CSS...

```
#pbar_outerdiv { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: thanks its working and one more doubt suppose i want stop bar movement in particular time like(0h, 0m ,30s) what i change done in my code

Comment: You can declare  var min=0, sec=0 ,hr=0; globally . and check it in animateUpdate() function . like function animateUpdate() {
    var perc = new Date().getTime() - timeStart;
     if(hr==0 && min==0 && sec==5){return;}
    if(perc < timeTotal) {
        updateProgress(perc);
        timer = setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeCount);
    } else {
       updateProgress(timeTotal);
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

With percentaje (line 11):

```
function updateProgress(percentage) {
    var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100,
        y = x.toFixed(3);
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').css("left", x + "%").text(x.toFixed(2) + '%');
}
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfRe/398/)

With hours, minutes and seconds:

```
var seconds = 1000;
var minutes = seconds * 60;
var hours = minutes * 60;
var days = hours * 24;
var years = days * 365;

function updateProgress(percentage) {

    var x = (percentage/timeTotal)*100,
        y = x.toFixed(3);
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').css("left", x + "%").text( Math.floor(percentage/hours) + 'h ' +  Math.floor(percentage/minutes) + 'm ' +  Math.floor(percentage/seconds) + 's');
}
```

[SEE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfRe/399/)

I think for that you should use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
var timeTotal = 2500,
    timeStart = 0,
    cFlag = false;

var seconds = 1000;
var minutes = seconds * 60;
var hours = minutes * 60;
var days = hours * 24;
var years = days * 365;

function updateProgress() {

    var time = new Date().getTime() - timeStart;
    var x = (time/timeTotal)*100,
        y = x.toFixed(3);
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').css("left", x + "%").text( Math.floor(time/hours) + 'h ' +  Math.floor(time/minutes) + 'm ' +  Math.floor(time/seconds) + 's');
    
    if(time <= timeTotal && cFlag) {
        requestAnimationFrame(updateProgress);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
        if (cFlag === false) {
            cFlag = true;
            timeStart = new Date().getTime();
            updateProgress();
        }
        else {
            cFlag = false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid grey; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
<div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: lightblue; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
<div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">0h 0m 0s</div>
</div>

<p>Click once to start!</p>
<p>Click again to toggle Start/Stop</p>
```

**UPDATED WITH PAUSE ALLOW AND RESUME:**

```js
var timeTotal = 5 * minutes,
   timePaused = 0,
    timePausedStart = 0,
    timeStart = 0,
    cFlag = false,
    stopped = false;

var seconds = 1000;
var minutes = seconds * 60;
var hours = minutes * 60;
var days = hours * 24;
var years = days * 365;

function updateProgress() {
    
    if( !timePausedStart ) { // if not paused
      var time = new Date().getTime() - timeStart - timePaused;
      
      var x = (time/timeTotal)*100,
          y = x.toFixed(3);
      $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", x + "%");
      $('#pbar_innertext').css("left", x + "%").text( Math.floor(time/hours%24) + 'h ' +  Math.floor(time/minutes%60) + 'm ' +  Math.floor(time/seconds) + 's');

      if(time > timeTotal) {
        cFlag = false;
      }

      if( Math.floor(time/seconds) == 3*60+30 && !stopped){ // pause at 3 m 30 s
       stopped = true;
        pause();      
      }
    }
    
    if( cFlag )
      requestAnimationFrame(updateProgress);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pbar_outerdiv').click(function() {
        if (cFlag === false) {
            cFlag = true;
            timeStart = new Date().getTime();
            timePaused = 0;
            updateProgress();
        } else if( cFlag === true && timePausedStart ){ // reset pause
            timePaused += new Date().getTime() - timePausedStart;
        timePausedStart = 0;
        }
        else {
           pause();
        }
    });
});

var pause = function(){
  timePausedStart = new Date().getTime();
};
```

```css
#pbar_outerdiv { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid grey; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
<div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: lightblue; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
<div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">0h 0m 0s</div>
</div>

<p>Click once to start!</p>
<p>Click again to toggle Start/Stop</p>
```

Comment: how can i control the speed of the bar .suppose i want complete the movement in one hour. now it is just 2 second

Comment: Change `timeTotal` to `1 * hours`. You have setted `timeTotal` to 2500 (two seconds and half).

Comment: thanks  its working and one more doubt suppose i want stop bar movement in particular time like(0h, 3m ,30s) what i change done in my code

Comment: Check my updated answer. I added a pause and resume :) You can pause with click and resume at the same moment. I added a auto-pause at 3 min 30 s too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing `(percentage / 1000).toFixed(2)`, you can use `percentage` to split your time in millisecond to `h:m's.ms`

You can simply compute the desired values with integer divisions

```
h  = Math.floor(percentage / 3600000);
m  = Math.floor((percentage - h * 3600000) / 60000);
s  = Math.floor((percentage - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000);
ms = Math.floor(percentage - h * 3600000 - m * 60000 - s * 1000);
```

Then, you can just use `toString()` to convert your int to strings. I concatenated the values with `0` and and used `slice()` to  keep only the two last character. This allow you to print hours, minutes, ... in two digits format

```
text = ("0" + h.toString() ).slice(-2) + ":"  +
       ("0" + m.toString() ).slice(-2) + "'"  +
       ("0" + s.toString() ).slice(-2) + "\"" +
       ("0" + ms.toString()).slice(-2);
```